# How to get the window width and height in stylesheet file using react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, function, react-hooks

I have a function for detecting the window width and height on changing the layout.

The function for detecting width and height work fine but the problem is using them on stylesheet file.

The error is: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

My Function:

```
import { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export function useDimensions () {

    const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(Dimensions.get('window').width);
    const [windowHeight, setWindowHeight] = useState(Dimensions.get('window').height);

    useEffect(() => {
        
        const callback = () => {
            setWindowWidth(Dimensions.get('window').width);
            setWindowHeight(Dimensions.get('window').height);
        }
    
        Dimensions.addEventListener('change', callback);
    
    }, []);
  
    return {windowWidth, windowHeight};
};
```

Here is what I have tried in stylesheet (custom global stylesheet file) :

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Colors from "./Colors";
import { windowHeight, windowWidth } from '../App/Components/Dimensions';
import { useDimensions } from '../App/Components/TestDimesions';

// Here is the problem : Invalid hook call...
const orientation = useDimensions();

const Global = StyleSheet.create({
test:{
 width: windowWidht
}
});

export default Global
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hooks only inside react components. Since `useDimensions` is a hook you can only use it like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const orientation = useDimensions();

  return (
    <View style={[styles.test, { width: orientation.windowWidth }]} />
  )
}
```

Comment: I know this way. But I am looking forward to use that inside stylesheet.

Comment: There's no any. You can use this directly in your stylesheet: test: { width: Dimensions.get('window').width }, but if device's orientation will be changed afterwards, it will not be updated. Why? Because in react data changes are reflected only through react components

Answer (score 0):

Other than the fact hooks must be called inside a function use should remove the eventlistener inside the useEffect.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    //here 
    const listener = Dimensions.addEventListener('change', callback);
    return () => listener.remove();
}, []);
```

Comment: It will return error in react native cli.

Comment: It is just a deprecated hook.

Comment: Instead we can use listen.remove()

Answer (score 0):

Use can get height and width simply by **window.innerHeight** and **window.innerWidth**. By this two you can get height and width of windows.

Comment: It works but only for the time orientation not update.

Comment: You need to add one event listener named "resize" in window, which will continuously give you window's height and width.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your function like this:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export const ScreenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
export const ScreenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

And you can use it by importing:

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Colors from "./Colors";
import { ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight } from '../App/Components/TestDimesions';

const Global = StyleSheet.create({
  test:{
    width: ScreenWidth,
  }
});

export default Global
```